# How to create dynamic column with different values

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created a dynamic table query that shows all the closed hours of the current day. This is my query:

```
select TO_CHAR(
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1),
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
       ) AS date_hour
from   DUAL
connect by
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1)
        < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

I want this table to have a second column, called "machine", which can have 3 different machine types (MAQ1, MAQ2, MAQ3). I wanted my calendar table to create the 24 rows of each hour of the current day for each machine.

The expected result would be something like this:

| date_hour | machine |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-09 00 | MAQ1_2023-08-09 00 |
| 2023-08-09 01 | MAQ1_2023-08-09 01 |
| 2023-08-09 02 | MAQ1_2023-08-09 02 |
| ... | ... |
| 2023-08-09 22 | MAQ1_2023-08-09 22 |
| 2023-08-09 23 | MAQ1_2023-08-09 23 |
| 2023-08-09 00 | MAQ2_2023-08-09 00 |
| 2023-08-09 01 | MAQ2_2023-08-09 01 |
| 2023-08-09 02 | MAQ2_2023-08-09 02 |
| ... | ... |
| 2023-08-09 22 | MAQ2_2023-08-09 22 |
| 2023-08-09 23 | MAQ2_2023-08-09 23 |
| 2023-08-09 00 | MAQ3_2023-08-09 00 |
| 2023-08-09 01 | MAQ3_2023-08-09 01 |
| 2023-08-09 02 | MAQ3_2023-08-09 02 |
| ... | ... |
| 2023-08-09 22 | MAQ3_2023-08-09 22 |
| 2023-08-09 23 | MAQ3_2023-08-09 23 |

It is possible?

Comment: Do you only need 3 machine types, or does it depend on other data, etc?
Would you be willing to use a `UNION` statement or maybe a "Cartesian product"?

Comment: @tgolisch actually it depends on other table that has the machine names, but there will always be the same 5 different machines (in the question I put only 3 machines to simplify the example). How would that look using a UNION with the machine table? or with a cartesian product?

Answer (score 0):

If there are always the same number of machines, you could just do a `UNION`. It is (imo) fairly simple to use

```
select TO_CHAR(
     TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1),
     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
   ) AS date_hour, 
     'MAQ1_' + TO_CHAR(
     TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1),
     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
   ) AS Machine
from   DUAL
connect by
   TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1)
    < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY

UNION

select TO_CHAR(
     TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1),
     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
   ) AS date_hour, 
     'MAQ2_' + TO_CHAR(
     TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1),
     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
   ) AS Machine
from   DUAL
connect by
   TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1)
    < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY

UNION

select TO_CHAR(
     TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1),
     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
   ) AS date_hour, 
     'MAQ3_' + TO_CHAR(
     TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1),
     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
   ) AS Machine
from   DUAL
connect by
   TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * (LEVEL - 1)
    < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```